# Структура сложноподчиненного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с предложением: "Но тотчас же пришла мысль, что если ему стыдно, то это тем лучше, потому что он должен нести стыд".

Никак не могу уразуметь, что откуда растет. Я рассуждаю следующим образом: "Но тотчас же пришла мысль" - главная часть, "что если ему стыдно" - придаточное определительное (мысль какая?), а вот дальше стопор. Является ли третья часть "то это тем лучше" по отношению ко второй "что если ему стыдно" главным предложением? "Если" - это условный союз. Тем лучше при каком условии? Если ему стыдно. Тогда неужели в этом предложении две главные части и две придаточных?

Я запуталась... Буду очень признательна за помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно так,третье простое предложение будет главным для второго и четвёртого, а само оно придаточное для первого:

*[1 тотчас же пришла мысль], (2 что (если ему стыдно), [3 то (это тем лучше]),(4 потому что он должен нести стыд).*

*тотчас же пришла мысль (какая?),  что это тем лучше ( при каком условии? когда?), (если ему стыдно), (почему лучше?)  потому что он должен нести стыд.*